# API Gateway DNS doesn't work without HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53, api-gateway

i am beginner with AWS.

I made a **POST endpoint** with **API GATEWAY**. (got xxx.execute-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com)

Then, i made A **Custom DNS** in **API GATEWAY** tool. (certificate manager, route53)

In Postman, i can reach https://mydns.com but can't reach mydns.com (without HTTPS in front).

i got **Error: connect ECONNREFUSED**

I would like to be able to reach my dns without https in front of the URL.

I have POST/GET REQUEST, and i think, something wrong with http but can't find.

do you have any ideas please ?

thanks by advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon API Gateway endpoints are HTTPS, not HTTP, that's why you are getting the **ECONNREFUSED** error. There's no way around it.

Comment: You're right, of course, that API Gateway will only accept TLS requests. However, you can get around it by using another services to initiate the TLS connection terminated by API Gateway. For example, one could use Cloudfront with an origin pointing to the API Gateway.

Comment: Yes, sure you can do that. But the question is if you can have plain HTTP with API Gateway.

Answer (score 1):

With **API Gateway** http endpoints are not possible. You can set up a **CloudFront** distribution to redirect http traffic to your https destination (API Gateway)